# Access google cloud spanner database list using service account

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner, google-iam

We have created cloud spanner instance and databases on google cloud console.

Following code snippet which we are executing.

```
def getDatabaseList(self,):
    try:
        parent = "projects/"+self._PROJECT_NAME + "/instances/" + self._INSTANCE_NAME
        response = self.service.projects().instances().databases().list(parent=parent).execute()
    except Exception, e:
        logging.info("Exception while getDatabaseList %s", e)
        return False
    return response
```

In the above code snippet is self.service is object googleapiclinet library build object.

We are getting below exception while executing above code snippet using service account id.

```
Exception while getDatabaseList <HttpError 403 when requesting https://spanner.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<projectName>/instances/<instanceName>/databases?alt=json&key=<APIKEY>

returned "Resource projects/<projectName>/instances/<instanceName> is missing IAM permission: spanner.databases.list.">
```

Reference document [cloud spanner IAM](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/grant-permissions)

Answer (score 1):

The following link shows an example to list Databases in an instance using Python Spanner Client Library
https://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner/blob/main/samples/samples/snippets.py#L144

Regarding the IAM permission issue it seems you have not set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. @ACimander answer is correct.

You can also use gcloud to authenticate using service account by

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account SERVICE_ACCOUNT@DOMAIN.COM --key-file=/path/key.json --project=PROJECT_ID
```

More information on this can be found in https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but hopefully this helps: Did you set path to your service-account's json file correctly? I wasted half a day playing with the permissions until I figured out that I simply missed a an env key.

```
set export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/your/service_account/key.json
```